# How to get whether the pressed key is backspace or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, input, onkeyup

I have a `input text` which used to filter data in a table using the `onkeyup` event

```
<input id="NameFilterText" type="text" onkeyup="return filterDataRow('NameFilterText','Name'); return false;" /></td>
```

I'm calling this JavaScript function in the `onkeyup` to the filter data

```
function filterDataRow(field, name) {
    var textBox = document.getElementById(field);
    var columnName = name;
    var table = document.getElementById('table1');
    var headRow = table.rows[0];
    var column = 0
    var text = textBox.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < headRow.cells.length; i++) {
        var cellName = headRow.cells[i].innerHTML;
        if (cellName == columnName) {
            column = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {

        table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row'; // execute only when pressing backspace

        for (var v = 0; v < text.length; v++) {
            var CurCell = table.rows[i].cells[column];
            var CurCont = CurCell.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
            var reg = new RegExp(text + ".*", "i");

            if (CurCont.match(reg) == null) {
                table.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't want to execute that commented line if the pressed key is not `backspace`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.getElementById('NameFilterText');
var keydown=0;
input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        keydown=1;
    return false;
};
```

Now in your code filterDataRow()

```
if(keydown=1){  do your thing. and set keydown = 0 again}
```

Hope it Helps !

Comment: Put that code and put a alert in the if statement. But it didn't work :(

if(keydown==1){ alert('A'); keydown=0; }

Comment: if (window.event.keyCode == 8) table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the onkeyup event to this:

```
<input ... onkeyup="filterDataRow('NameFilterText','Name');" />
```

Then inside the function edit the line you want to be executed only one time adding this if-statement:

```
if (window.event.keyCode == 8) table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
```

Comment: I edited my answer, do what I wrote and it will work

Comment: I changed as you mentioned. But it didn't work..
alert('A');
if (window.event.keyCode == 8) table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
alert('B');

alert('A') worked and alert('B') didn't

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library called [keysight](https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight) that does this kind of thing for all keyboard keys:

```
node.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var key = keysight(event).key
    if(key === '\b') {
      console.log("We got one!")
    }
})
```